# Who’s Bar Tutni

Tags: talmud-gemara, historical-figures, masechet-kereitot

The Gemara in Keritot 4b has Reish Lakish quoting someone named בר תאוטני. If my AlHatorah search was correct, it seems this is the only place in Shas he is mentioned. Does anyone have more info on who this Bar Tutni is?

Comment: Also the parallel Gemara in Shabbos 71a (where it's spelled בר תוטני).

Comment: @Meir Ah I guess that’s why it didn’t come up in my search :)

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%91/%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%99